# Authenticating with Azure Repos git module sources in an Azure Pipelines build

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I'm currently creating a pipeline for Azure DevOps to validate and apply a Terraform configuration to different subscription.

My terraform configuration uses modules, those are "hosted" in other repositories in the same Azure DevOps Project as the terraform configuration.

Sadly, when I try to perform `terraform init` to fetch those modules, the pipeline task "hang" there waiting for credentials input.

As recommanded in the [Pipeline Documentation on Running Git Commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=vsts&tabs=yaml) I tried to add a `checkout` step with the `persistCredentials:true` attribute.

From what I can see in the log of the task (see bellow), the credentials information are added specifically to the current repo and are not usable for other repos.

**The command performed when adding `persistCredentials:true`**

```
2018-10-22T14:06:54.4347764Z ##[command]git config http.https://my-org@dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_git/my-repo.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***"
```

**The output of terraform init task**

```
2018-10-22T14:09:24.1711473Z terraform init -input=false
2018-10-22T14:09:24.2761016Z Initializing modules...
2018-10-22T14:09:24.2783199Z - module.my-module
2018-10-22T14:09:24.2786455Z   Getting source "git::https://my-org@dev.azure.com/my-org/my-project/_git/my-module-repo?ref=1.0.2"
```

How can I setup the git credentials to work for other repositories ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, what I ended up doing is tokenizing `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` in terraform configuration. I used Tokenzization task in Azure DevOps where `__` prefix and suffix is used to identify and replace tokens with actual variables (it is customizable but I find double underscores best for not interfering with any code that I have)

```
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
    displayName: 'Replace tokens'
    inputs:
      targetFiles: |
       **/*.tfvars
       **/*.tf
      tokenPrefix: '__'
      tokenSuffix: '__'
```

Something like `find $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ -type f -name 'main.tf' -exec sed -i 's~__SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN__~$(System.AccessToken)~g' {} \;` would also work if you do not have ability to install custom extensions to your DevOps organization.

My terraform main.tf looks like this:

```
module "app" {
  source = "git::https://token:__SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN__@dev.azure.com/actualOrgName/actualProjectName/_git/TerraformModules//azure/app-service?ref=__app-service-module-ver__"
  ....
}
```

It's not beautiful but it gets the job done. Module source (at the time of writing) does not support variable input from terraform. So what we can do is to use Terrafile it's an open source project helping with keeping up with the modules and different versions of the same module you might use by keeping a simple YAML file next to your code. It seems that it's no longer being actively maintained, however it just works: https://github.com/coretech/terrafile
my example of Terrafile:

```
app:
    source:  "https://token:__SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN__@dev.azure.com/actualOrgName/actualProjectName/_git/TerraformModules"
    version: "feature/handle-twitter"
app-stable:
    source:  "https://token:__SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN__@dev.azure.com/actualOrgName/actualProjectName/_git/TerraformModules"
    version: "1.0.5"
```

Terrafile by default download your modules to ./vendor directory so you can point your module source to something like:

```
module "app" {
  source = "./vendor/modules/app-stable/azure/app_service"
  ....
}
```

Now you just have to figure out how to execute `terrafile` command in the directory where Terrafile is present.
My azure.pipelines.yml example:

```
- script: curl -L https://github.com/coretech/terrafile/releases/download/v0.6/terrafile_0.6_Linux_x86_64.tar.gz | tar xz -C $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)
  displayName: Install Terrafile

- script: |
    cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
    $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/terrafile
  displayName: Download required modules
```

Answer (score 3):

You have essentially two ways of doing this.

## Pre-requisite

Make sure that you read and, depending on your needs, that you apply the [Enable scripts to run Git commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#enable-scripts-to-run-git-commands) section from the "Run Git commands in a script" doc.

## Solution #1: dynamically insert the `System.AccessToken` (or a PAT, but I would not recommend it) at pipeline runtime

You could to this either by:

- inserting a replacement token such as `__SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN__` in your code (as [Nilsas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61693543/4374048) suggests) and use some token replacement code or the `qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens` task to insert the value. The disadvantage of this solution is that you would also have to replace the token when you run you `terraform` locally.
- using some code to replace all `git::https://dev.azure.com` text with `git::https://YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN@dev.azure.com`.

I used the second approach by using the following bash task script (it searches `terragrunt` files but you can adapt to `terraform` files without much change):

```
- bash: |
    find $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ -type f -name 'terragrunt.hcl' -exec sed -i 's~git::https://dev.azure.com~git::https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com~g' {} \;
```

[Abu Belai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62264154/4374048) offers a PowerShell script to do something similar.

This type of solution does not however work if modules in your `terraform` modules `git` repo call themselves modules in another `git` repo, which was our case.

## Solution #2: adding globally the access token in the `extraheader` of the url of your `terraform` modules `git` repos

This way, all the modules' repos, called directly by your code or called indirectly by the called modules' code, will be able to use your access token. I did so by adding the following step before your `terraform`/`terragrunt` calls:

```
- bash: |
    git config --global http.https://dev.azure.com/<your-org>/<your-first-repo-project>/_git/<your-first-repo>.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
    git config --global http.https://dev.azure.com/<your-org>/<your-second-repo-project>/_git/<your-second-repo>.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
```

You will need to set the `extraheader` for each of the called `git` repos.

Beware that you might need to unset the `extraheader` after your `terraform` calls if your pipeline sets the `extraheader` several times on the same worker. This is because `git` can get confused with multiple `extraheader` declaration. You do this by adding to following step:

```
- bash: |
    git config --global --unset-all http.https://dev.azure.com/<your-org>/<your-first-repo-project>/_git/<your-first-repo>.extraheader
    git config --global --unset-all http.https://dev.azure.com/<your-org>/<your-second-repo-project>/_git/<your-second-repo>.extraheader
```

Comment: Please don't follow solution #2. You will find that you have agent machines that one way or another didn't have their extraheader cleared, and that your pipeline starts failing with git error 128. It is a horrible thing to try to track down.

Comment: On the other hand, solution #1 works well.

Comment: I get "fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@tfs.company.co.nz' when adding syste.accesstoken to module url. Any suggestions on how to work around that?

Comment: Solution 2 works great on Azure Hosted agents. New clean agent with every new run. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I did this

_ado_token.ps1

```
# used in Azure DevOps to allow terrform to auth with Azure DevOps GIT repos
$tfmodules = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -Recurse -Filter "*.tf"
foreach ($tfmodule in $tfmodules) {
    $content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($tfmodule.FullName).Replace("git::https://myorg@","git::https://" + $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN +"@")
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($tfmodule.FullName, $content)
}
```

azure-pipelines.yml

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  env: 
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    filePath: '_ado_token.ps1'
    pwsh: true
  displayName: '_ado_token.ps1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the issue by creating a Pipeline template that runs a inline powershell script. I then pull in the template as the Pipeline template a "resource" when using any terraform module form a different Repo.
The script will do a recursive search for all the .tf files. Then use regex to update all the module source urls.

I chose REGEX over tokenizing the module url, because this will make sure the modules can be pulled in on a development machine without any changes to the source.

```
parameters:
- name: terraform_directory
  type: string

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Tokenize TF-Module Sources
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      
      script: |
        $regex = "https://*(.+)dev.azure.com"
        $tokenized_url = "https://token:$($env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)@dev.azure.com"

        Write-Host "Recursive Search in ${{ parameters.terraform_directory }}"
        $tffiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "${{ parameters.terraform_directory }}" -Filter "*main.tf" -Recurse -Force

        Write-Host "Found $($tffiles.Count) files ending with 'main.tf'"
        if ($tffiles) { Write-Host $tffiles }

        $tffiles | % {
          Write-Host "Updating file $($_.FullName)"
          $content = Get-Content $_.FullName

          Write-Host "Replace Strings: $($content | Select-String -Pattern $regex)"
          
          $content -replace $regex, $tokenized_url | Set-Content $_.FullName -Force

          Write-Host "Updated content"
          Write-Host (Get-Content $_.FullName)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the best way to do this is exactly the same as with any other Git provider. It is only for Azure DevOps that I have ever come across the `extraheader` approach. I have always used this, and after not being able to get a satisfactory result with the other suggested approaches, I went back to it:

```
- script: |
    MY_TOKEN=foobar
    git config --global url."https://${MY_TOKEN}@dev.azure.com".insteadOf "https://dev.azure.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scenario:

You have two git repositories in one project.

`Repo1` contains the terraform module code.

`Repo2` contains the terraform code that points to `Repo1` (with a specific tag like `1.0.0`)  as the module source.

Your pipeline yaml is in `Repo2`.

Then this is how your module block of `Repo2` would look like:

```
module "alz" {
  source  = "git::https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_git/Repo1?ref=<tag>"
  .
  .
}
```

In your Azure pipeline,

You will first declare a repository resource for `Repo1` :

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Repo1
    type: git
    name: "<project>/Repo1"
```

Then checkout both the repositories in the pipeline, but persist the credentials for repo2.

```
  # Checkout Repo2  
  - checkout : self 

  # Checkout Repo1  
  - checkout : Repo1
    persistCredentials: 'true'
```

Even if you avoid the line `persistCredentials: 'true'`, make sure you checkout both the repositories. If you just checkout `self`, ie, Repo2 only, it may not work for fetching from Repo1 and will give error:

```
│ remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier
│ Repo1 does not exist or you do not have
│ permissions for the operation you are attempting.
```

Now set the credential, ie, System.AccessToken before `terraform init`. You can do this in two ways.

**Option 1:**

```
  - bash: |
      git config --global http.https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>/_git/Repo1.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
    displayName: Set Credential

  # Terraform Init
  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'init'
      workingDirectory: '$(working_dir)'
      backendServiceArm: $(sc_tf_backend)
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(backendRGName)
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(backendSAName)
      backendAzureRmContainerName: $(backendContainerName)
      backendAzureRmKey: $(backendBlobKey)
```

**Option 2:**

```
  - bash: |
      MY_TOKEN=$(System.AccessToken)
      git config --global url."https://${MY_TOKEN}@dev.azure.com".insteadOf "https://dev.azure.com"
    displayName: Set Credential

  # Terraform Init
  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'init'
      workingDirectory: '$(working_dir)'
      backendServiceArm: $(sc_tf_backend)
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(backendRGName)
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(backendSAName)
      backendAzureRmContainerName: $(backendContainerName)
      backendAzureRmKey: $(backendBlobKey)
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't think you can. Usually, you create another build and link to the artifacts from that build to use it in your current definition. That way you don't need to connect to a different Git repository