# Inconsistent failure when downloading terraform modules in azure pipelines

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-pipelines

working with a simple terraform build pipeline and everything seems to be according to plan except I get a "failed to download modules" error halfway through my terraform init step

So the step runs fine at first and I am able to begin initializing and downloading modules:

[image: Terraform Init step]

and here's where things get dicey, it then errors out saying it can't download modules due to host key verification failures and "could not read from remote repository"

### Errors

```
Error: Failed to download module
│ 
│ Could not download module "***_***_***_***_*******" (aks.tf:2) source code
│ from
│ "git::ssh://git@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com/v3/myOrg/Terraform/repo":
│ error downloading
│ 'ssh://git@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com/v3/***/Terraform/repo':
│ /usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into
│ '.terraform/modules/***_***_***_***_cluster'...
│ Host key verification failed.
│ fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
│ 
│ Please make sure you have the correct access rights
│ and the repository exists.
│
```

### **What I've tried:**

- I tried both dynamically inserting a PAT at runtime as well as adding the access token in the extra header of the url of terraform module git repos from the solution by Emmanuel Sciara in this page

[Authenticating with Azure Repos git module sources in an Azure Pipelines build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931994/authenticating-with-azure-repos-git-module-sources-in-an-azure-pipelines-build)

- I added an installsshkeytask

```
steps:
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    name: sshPrivateKey
    displayName: 'Download SSH Key'
    inputs:
      secureFile: 'pipelinekeys'
 
 
  - task: InstallSSHKey@0
    displayName: 'Install SSH Key'
    inputs:
      knownHostsEntry: '*'
      sshPublicKey: $(sshPublicKey)
      sshKeySecureFile: 'pipelinekeys'
```

- Manually adding the pipeline under pipeline permissions in Project Settings > Repositories > Repo > Settings > Security

### How its consumed

I'm calling the init step from a template in another repo

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Terraform Init'
    env:
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
      ARM_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
      script: |
        set -euo pipefail
        
        echo "Initialize"
        terraform init \
            -input=false \
            -backend-config="resource_group_name=${storage_rg}" \
            -backend-config="storage_account_name=${storage_Account}" \
            -backend-config="container_name=${blob_container}" \
            -backend-config="key=${blob_name}"
```

Any idea on what im missing? just need to be pointed in the right direction, not sure where the issue even is

Comment: Please post errors as text, not screenshots.

Comment: @MarkoE my apologies, amending now

Comment: "host key verification failed" means that ssh on your client (azure) does not like the key supplied by the host (`vs-ssh.visualstudio.com`). Make sure you either trust the host key on first use, or have put the correct host key into your ssh setup. (This is not a *Git* issue, it's purely ssh. Note that it's the *host* key, not the client key, here.)

Comment: This looks similar to a problem I saw in a different context.  I fixed it by doing the following: In the project containing the repo from which the modules are being downloaded, go to "Project Settings/Permissions", then click on the "Readers" group, and then the "Members" tab.  Add the "Build Service" account for the project containing your pipeline.

Comment: @torek yep that’s what it was. Boneheaded mistake on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a known host issue.

It didn’t work when I specified ‘*’ in the ssh install task on the pipeline

Had to run

```
ssh-keyscan -H -t rsa vs-ssh.visualstudio.com > $env:userprofile/.ssh/known_hosts
```

On my local machine then paste the contents into a variable in my pipeline and pass it through to the ssh install task

```
- task: InstallSSHKey@0
  displayName: ‘Install SSH Key’
  Inputs:
    KnownHostEntry: ‘$(put-variable-here)’
    SshPublicKey: ‘$(put-public-key-var-her)’
    SshKeySecureFile: ‘put-private-key-file-here’
```

https://dev.to/pwd9000/connect-terraform-to-azure-devops-git-repos-over-ssh-163c